# Can't pull some images in Docker

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

When I'm trying to pull images I get in stuck.

```
docker pull php:7-fpm
7-fpm: Pulling from library/php
f17d81b4b692: Already exists
376d99d019dc: Already exists
80b3573727f0: Already exists
2c492579cd1f: Waiting
```

I'm using Windows 10 Home with docker-toolbox running on VirtualBox.
How to beat this infinity `Waiting` ?

Comment: did you try `docker --debug pull php:7-fpm` and see if there's any log output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how, but after system reloading, all works fine.